# contrast of contrast with emmeans (second differences)

Tags: r, interaction, emmeans

I am using emmeans to conduct a contrast of a contrast (i.e., testing for an interaction effect through 1st/2nd differences).

It involves 3 steps:

1. estimate means using “emmeans”
2. estimate if there is a difference in means (1st difference) using “pairs”
3. estimate if there is a difference in the difference  (2nd difference) using ????

While I can execute steps 1 and 2 (see reprex below with fictions data), i’m stuck on step 3.  Tips?

(the contrast of a contrast shown in the vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html#contrasts) is for alternative functional forms, which is somewhat different than what I want to test)

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(emmeans)})

# create ex. data set.  1 row per respondent (dataset shows 2 resp). 
cedata.1 <- data.frame( id    =  c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),    
                        QES    = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,3,3),   # Choice set   
                        Alt    = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),   # Alt 1 or Alt 2 in  choice set 
                        Choice = c(0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1),   # Dep variable.  if  Chosen (1) or not (0)
                        LOC    = c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1),   # Indep variable per Choice set, binary categorical 
                        SIZE   = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1),   # Indep variable per Choice set, binary categorical 
                        gender = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)    # Indep variable per indvidual, binary categorical 
)


# estimate model
glm.model <- glm(Choice ~  LOC*SIZE, data=cedata.1, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

# estimate means (i.e.,  values used to calc 1st diff). 
comp1.loc.size <- emmeans(glm.model, ~ LOC * SIZE) 

# calculate 1st diff (and p value)
pairs(comp1.loc.size, simple = "SIZE")   # gives result I want
#> LOC = 0:
#>  contrast estimate   SE  df z.ratio p.value
#>  0 - 1       -1.39 1.73 Inf -0.800  0.4235 
#> 
#> LOC = 1:
#>  contrast estimate   SE  df z.ratio p.value
#>  0 - 1        0.00 1.73 Inf  0.000  1.0000 
#> 
#> Results are given on the log odds ratio (not the response) scale.

# calculate 2nd diff (and p value)
# ** the following gives the relevant values for doing the 2nd diff comparison (i.e., -1.39 and 0.00)...but how to make the statistical comparison?
pairs(comp1.loc.size, simple = "SIZE")
#> LOC = 0:
#>  contrast estimate   SE  df z.ratio p.value
#>  0 - 1       -1.39 1.73 Inf -0.800  0.4235 
#> 
#> LOC = 1:
#>  contrast estimate   SE  df z.ratio p.value
#>  0 - 1        0.00 1.73 Inf  0.000  1.0000 
#> 
#> Results are given on the log odds ratio (not the response) scale.
```

Comment: Where's the difference between the two diffs you showed in your example?

Comment: unsure what you mean? as i wrote in the last step under "calculate 2nd diff (and p-value)" I identify the values i want to compare (-1.39 and 0.00), but I'm unsure how to make that statistical comparison using emmeans/contrast/pairwise/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pairs(pairs(comp1.loc.size, simple = "SIZE"), by = NULL)`

Comment: elegant solution, thanks :) I tried to "vote up" your answer  but cant because I dont have the "reputation" to do it :(  Maybe somebody else can.

Comment: btw, just posted a few similar question here (perhaps you have a similarly elegant solution?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64482659/testing-contrast-of-contrast-first-second-difference-in-outcome

Comment: Actually, that code does not work for me. Is the "pairs" function from a certain package?

Comment: @Poza the pairs function mentioned here is from the emmeans package.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
# estimate means (i.e.,  values used to calc 1st diff). 
comp1.loc.size <- emmeans(glm.model, ~ LOC | SIZE) 

# second difference:
pairs(pairs(emmeans::regrid(comp1.loc.size)), by = NULL)
```

PS: This solution is almost a copy of the solution here: [Testing contrast of contrast (first/second difference) in outcome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64482659/testing-contrast-of-contrast-first-second-difference-in-outcome)