# Testing contrast of contrast (first/second difference) in outcome

Tags: emmeans

I want to conduct a contrast of a contrast (i.e., testing for an interaction effect through 1st/2nd differences), where the contrast refers to an outcome (predicted probability) **

It involves 3 steps:

(1) estimate predicted prob (several ways of doing this; I extracted from plot)

(2) calc if there is a difference in predict prob (1st difference) using “pairs”

(3) calc if there is a difference in the difference (2nd difference) using pairs.

I failed in steps (2) and (3). See my code in reprex below with fictious data. Is there a better way to do this?

** My recent S/O post showed [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64446605/contrast-of-contrast-with-emmeans-second-differences) showed how to do for “differences in marginal effects of regresser on probability”.  But this is a parallel question for  “differences in probability of an outcome” instead.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(emmeans)})

# create ex. data set.  1 row per respondent (dataset shows 2 resp). 
cedata.1 <- data.frame( id    =  c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),    
                        QES    = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,3,3),   # Choice set   
                        Alt    = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),   # Alt 1 or Alt 2 in  choice set 
                        Choice = c(0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1),   # Dep variable.  if  Chosen (1) or not (0)
                        LOC    = c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1),   # Indep variable per Choice set, binary categorical 
                        SIZE   = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1),   # Indep variable per Choice set, binary categorical 
                        gender = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)    # Indep variable per indvidual, binary categorical 
)


# estimate model
glm.model <- glm(Choice ~  LOC*SIZE, data=cedata.1, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

# Plot interaction on response scale (i.e., predict prob) 
zzz <- emmip(glm.model, LOC ~ SIZE, type = "response")   

# (1) Estimate predicted prob   (extract values where yvar=predicted prob)
zzz$data
#>   LOC SIZE      yvar        SE  df tvar xvar
#> 1   0    0 0.3333333 0.2721655 Inf    0    0
#> 2   1    0 0.5000000 0.3535534 Inf    1    0
#> 3   0    1 0.6666667 0.2721655 Inf    0    1
#> 4   1    1 0.5000000 0.2500000 Inf    1    1

# (2) calc 1st diff. 
### I tried following, but got an error ->  pairs(zzz$data, simple = "SIZE", by= NULL?

# (3) calc 2nd diff  
### I tried following, but got an error ->  pairs(pairs(zzz$data, simple = "SIZE"), by = NULL)
```

Comment: Use `emmeans()` not `emmip()`

Comment: but I want to test outcomes, not effects.  How can i get  emmeans()  to produce "predicted probabilities" instead? My understanding is that emmeans gives marginal effects instead?

Comment: If you mean you want differences instead of odds ratios, use regrid(emmeans(...))

Comment: I want "differences in "predicted probability" (the naturel metric of the dep var). I do not want differences in odds ratios.   And I do not want differences in marginal effects of regresser on probability (which you, thankfully, already solved for me in a related S/O post  (linked above).  Given that, can emmeans() help to do pairwise comparisons/contrast with predicted probability instead of marginal effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
emm <- regrid(emmeans(glm.model, ~ SIZE | LOC))
pairs(pairs(emm), by = NULL)
```

`emm` contains the predicted probabilities for the four factor combinations. They are not marginal results because we didn't average over anything. `pairs(emm)` obtains the SIZE differences at each location, then disregard the by variable the next time around.

BTW you could also do

```
contrast(emm, interaction = "pairwise")
```

Comment: Thx, very helpful. Clarifying point: in my simple reprex I showed just 2 regressors (LOC & SIZE), but my actual model has several.  So when i run this the results remind me that “results are averaged over levels of ZZZ” where ZZZ are the other regressors in my model.  So my question: how do I know what average values of ZZZ were used by regrid/emmeans when estimating the predict probs? Can i extract or obtain those values somehow so I can report them?  Thx

Comment: As coded above, the model predictions are averaged on the logit scale and then back-transformed. See `vignette("transformations")`